# Efficient/simple way to replace every occurrence but the last occurence of a substring in a string (str_replace_except_last)?

Tags: php, string, function

Imagine the following inputs and the desired output after `str_replace_except_last($replace_except_last,$replacement,$text)`:

```
func(".","",12.833331.3198912.980289012.92) => 128333313198912980289012.92
func(".","",31.0) => 31.0
func(".","",8) => 8
func(".","",9190.1.1.1....1.1.....1) => 919011111.1
func(".","",98909090....) => 98909090.
func("beer","","My beer is the best beer.") => My is the best beer.
func("it","fit,"Is it really it or is it not?") => Is fit really fit or is it not?
```

Want to perform the simple task of removing every occurrence of a character or substring but NOT the last occurrence. Basically this is what `str_replace` does, however it replaces any occurrence.

Hint: Made some experiments with `substr_count` however I did not find how to replace ocurrence number X in a string easily?

Comment: @Blackbam, If you are interested I added the performance information in my answer.

Comment: Thx yes very interesting intuition told me that probably the PHP native functions on strings would perform a bit better than arrays (this probably only matters if the function is looped very often ;-) Maybe the result is not as  clear if compared to a regex solution? I may test later.

Comment: Regex usually takes more time to run (and also more memory). The regex function by @Surberus took 20M and ~0.03 sec (twice the time of the string function, a bit more than half the time of the array function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will be the most efficient/simple solution (however I didn't run it though some run-time test).

```
function str_replace_except_last($needle, $replace, $text) {
    if ($last_pos = strrpos($text, $needle)) {
        $text = str_replace($needle, $replace, substr($text, 0, $last_pos)) . substr($text, $last_pos);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Since the question was also related to efficiency, I decided to test the two versions (mine and the one offered by @Don'tPanic, which is based on arrays).

> First - Let me just say that **premature optimization is the root of all evil**

Now that we are done with that we can move next :)

I decided to create a random string of 10M chars, the string will also contain `.` (which will be our needle).

I run the two functions 1000 times on same string and checked the average time it took each function to run.
I also checked how much memory each function took to work.

Here are the results:

1. The creation of the 10M characters string took 2.3 seconds.
2. The string function run on average **0.016** second (each iteration)
   The memory usage was **9.8M**
3. The array function run on average **0.049** second (each iteration)
   The memory usage was **45.1M**

Here is the complete code (if you want to run it yourself):

```
$ITERATIONS = 1000;

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function func_str($needle, $replace, $text) {
    $m1 = memory_get_usage();

    if ($last_pos = strrpos($text, $needle)) {
        $text = str_replace($needle, $replace, substr($text, 0, $last_pos)) . substr($text, $last_pos);
    }

    $m2 = memory_get_usage();
    //echo "memory diff ". ($m2-$m1) ."\n";

    return $text;
}

function func_arr($needle, $replace, $text) {
    $m1 = memory_get_usage();

    $array = explode($replace, $text, substr_count($text, $replace));
    $text = implode($replacement, $array);
    $m2 = memory_get_usage();
    //echo "memory diff ". ($m2-$m1) ."\n";

    return $text;
}

$m1 = memory_get_usage();
$s = microtime(true);
$str1 = generateRandomString(10000000);
$e = microtime(true);
echo "create took ". ($e-$s) ." seconds\n";
echo "Number of occurances: " . substr_count($str1, '.') . "\n";

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $ITERATIONS; $i++) {
    func_str(".","",$str1);
}
$e = microtime(true);
echo "remove took ". ($e-$s) ." seconds, avg: ". ($e-$s)/$ITERATIONS ."\n";

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $ITERATIONS; $i++) {
    func_arr(".","",$str1);
}
$e = microtime(true);
echo "remove took ". ($e-$s) ." seconds, avg: ". ($e-$s)/$ITERATIONS ."\n";
```

(I commented out the output of the memory usage inside the functions, if you want it you can remove the comment).

Comment: @Blackbam, I know it works, I'm just not sure this is the most efficient way :) thats all

Comment: I think that this, an array method, or a regex should be similar enough in terms of performance that _not_ using whichever method you prefer wouldn't be a worthwhile optimization. I like the string functions only approach too.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I think that if we talk about performance - the explode function will be less effective and take more time (you need to create a new array with new elements, and you need to allocate each of the elements the memory and so on). I'll try to run a quick performance test and will post the resutls :)

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I added the performance information If you want to have a loko

Answer (score 3):

Split the main string on the string to replace (except for the last piece), then join it back together with the replacement.

```
function str_replace_except_last($replace, $replacement, $text) {
    $array = explode($replace, $text, substr_count($text, $replace));
    return implode($replacement, $array);
}
```

Comment: Works great however I prefer the without array solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks! To each their own. I kinda love arrays.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, nice solution. Got voteup from me too :)

Comment: Thanks! I liked it a lot more after I remembered about limiting explode.

Answer (score 1):

You could use preg_replace to remove every occurrence except the last. The regex does a look ahead and only replaces if the pattern also exists later in the string.

```
$str = '66.768.876876.8.7876';
$pattern = '.';

echo(str_replace_except_last($pattern, '', $str));

function str_replace_except_last($replace_except_last, $replacement, $text)
{
    $pattern = preg_quote($replace_except_last);
    return preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '(?=[^' . $pattern . ']*' . $pattern . '[^' . $pattern . ']*)/', $replacement, $text);
}
```

Comment: Works great however I prefer the without regex solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement , i think you should use preg_replace,strripos and substr. Please try below code , it is simple to understand.

```
<?php

    function str_replace_without_last($text,$text_to_replace,$text_to_replace_with)
    {

        $text_position = strripos($text,$text_to_replace);
        $suffix_text = substr($text,$text_position);
        $prefix_text = substr($text,0,$text_position);
        $text_to_replace_with = $text_to_replace_with;
        $number_of_text_occurences = substr_count($prefix_text, $text_to_replace);
        $prefix = preg_replace("/$text_to_replace/",$text_to_replace_with,$prefix_text);
        $result = $prefix.$suffix_text;
        return $result;

    }

    // Call function for testing

    $text = "My beer is the best beer and good beer.";
    $text_to_replace = "beer";
    $text_to_replace_with = "";
    $result = str_replace_without_last($text,$text_to_replace,$text_to_replace_with);
    echo $result;

?>
```

I hope this will work for you , Feel free to comment.